# pushing empty data into nested array in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I'm kinda new to angular and would appreciate any assistance. I am creating a simple reporting system which has following structure

A Report can have many Subreports

and Subreports can have many Tasks.

Here's the my code structure

```
var Report = {
        "ReportId":1,
        "ReportDate":"02/05/2015",
        "SubReport":[
            {
                "SubId": 1,
                "ProjectName": "An ice sculpture",
                "ProjectDeliverable":"My Deliverable1",
                "ProjectTarget":"My Target1",
                "Task":[
                 {
                     "TaskPerformed": "Task Performed 1 of 1",
                     "TimeSpent": 3,
                     "ResultAchieved": "Result 1 of 1" ,            
                     "PlannedActivity": "Planned Activity 1 of 1"   
                 }]
            }]
    };




 <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">


                                    <tbody ng-repeat="subrep in Report.SubReport">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed">
                                                    <thead ng-show="$index==0">
                                                        <tr>
                                                            <th >ACTION</th>

                                                            <th>Project Name</th>
                                                            <th>Project Deliverable</th>
                                                            <th>Target</th>
                                                            <th>Task Performed</th>

                                                            <th>Time Spent(Hrs)</th>
                                                            <th>Result Achieved</th>
                                                            <th>Planned Activity</th>
                                                            <th >ACTION</th>
                                                        </tr>
                                                    </thead>
                                                    <tbody>

                                                        <tr ng-show="$index==0" ng-repeat="tsk in subrep.Task">
                                                            <td>
                                                                <div class="btn-group">
                                                                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="" ng-click="addNew()" ng-

show="$parent.$index==0" title="New SubReport" >
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                                                    </a>

                                                                    <a class="btn btn-green" href=""  title="Edit SubReport" data-

toggle="modal" data-target="#">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                                                                    </a>


                                                                    <a class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete SubReport" href="">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                                                                    </a></div>
</td>
                                                            <td>{{subrep.ProjectName}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{subrep.ProjectDeliverable}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{subrep.ProjectTarget}}</td>



                                                            <td>{{tsk.TaskPerformed}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{tsk.TimeSpent}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{tsk.ResultAchieved}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{tsk.PlannedActivity}}</td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <div class="btn-group">
                                                                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="" data-toggle="modal" title="New 

Task" data-target="#NewTask">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                                                    </a>
                                                                       <a class="btn btn-green" href="tsk={{$index}}/sub={{$parent.

$index}}" title="Edit Task" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#defaultmodal">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                                                                    </a>

                                                                    <a class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete Task" href="">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                                                                    </a>


                                                                    </div>
</td>
                                                        </tr>
                                                        <tr ng-show="$index>0" ng-repeat="tsk in subrep.Task">


                                                            <td colspan="4"></td>



                                                            <td>{{tsk.TaskPerformed}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{tsk.TimeSpent}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{tsk.ResultAchieved}}</td>
                                                            <td>{{tsk.PlannedActivity}}</td>
                                                            <td>
                                                                <div class="btn-group">
                                                                    <a class="btn btn-green" href="tsk={{$index}}/sub={{$parent.

$index}}" title="Edit Task" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#defaultmodal">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
                                                                    </a>

                                                                    <a class="btn btn-danger" title="Delete Task" href="">
                                                                        <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
                                                                    </a>
                                                                    </div>
</td>

                                                            <td>

                                                            </td>
                                                        </tr>


                                                    </tbody>
                                                </table>
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>

                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

my Factory which attempts to save a subreport in an existing Report

```
fac.AddSubReport = function (data) {
    Report.SubReport.push(data);       
      return Report;
}
return fac;

enter code here
```

I have two challenges..

1. When I get the data from a txt file I can't get to display the my table with a single header as below :

   SubId | ProjName | TaskId | TaskName

   1. Abc.       1.        Task1-1
      ..........       2.        Task1-2
      ..........       3.        Task1-3
   2. Proj2.     1.        Task2-1
       .........       2.        Task2-2

   Here I used nested ng-repeat but I seem to iterate over the tasks using ng-show first line of subreport info if $parent.$index=0, but it keeps creating a new table for the subreport.
2. How do I add/push a subreport to a report without having a task

I would appreciate any assistance. I'm using my phone else would have posted some of my code.

Notice how i have used the ng-repeat on the Task so as to show only subreports with task index =0. I only want to have the subreport information displayed only on the first task. I am using a Modal to save the subreporrt, but the problem is that no subreport is displayed since as at the time of saving a subreport it doesnt have a task- henc its not displayed.

I would want to know the best approach to saving a subreport first before adding a task to it and how i can get the information to be displayed correctly on the table

Comment: Sir some code please :)

Comment: @sudhansu I have updated the information to include codes

Comment: Guess nobody wanna help out... after alot of editing i was able to achieve the table alignment by following the method here [link]  plnkr.co/edit/b3S6HuijA6TrxgUGSJv7?p=preview  –  Diego Vieira... Still having issues with saving data into the Subreport though